# MS SQL compare two table with exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables like this

Tableyesterday

```
Column1 Column2  Column3     Column4 
John     5584    samsung     2017-08-31 23:43:06.867
Bob      4512    apple       2017-08-31 23:43:06.867
Hana     1881    nokia       2017-08-31 23:43:06.867
Hanz     4866    alcatel     2017-08-31 23:43:06.867
Nicol    48633   android     2017-08-31 23:43:06.867  ---gone
```

Tabletoday

```
Column1 Column2     Column3     Column4 
John     5584       samsung     2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---same entry
Bob      4542446    apple       2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---change in column2
Hana     1881       halophone   2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---change in column3 
Hanz     4866       alcatel     2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---same entry
Mark     486654     alcatel     2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---new entry
```

I need to select today's changes and insert into tableofchanges. Only these two rows have to be selected:

Tableofchanges

```
Bob      4542446    apple       2017-09-01 23:43:06.867
Hana     1881       halophone   2017-09-01 23:43:06.867
```

I created this query, but I cannot include Column4. However, if I do select without Column4, I would not see Column4 in the result:

```
select Column1, Column2,Column3 from [dbo].[tabletoday]
except
select Column1, Column2,Column3 from [dbo].[Tableyesterday]
```

Comment: Different tables for different days? For real?!?

Comment: could be declared or temporary tables?

Comment: So its only `Column1` which is the key between the two?

Comment: @jamiec column 4.. tables ar without  fix PK

Comment: DOes the fact that `Column4` has all the same values in it not indicate why that might be a problem!?

Comment: There are so many things wrong here....but sticking to the question it is not clear to me what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: Tell me you have `ID` or at least column that cannot be updated/changed?

Comment: if you just want updated rows and not new rows, you cannot use except. since except returns every row that does exist in first table and not exists in second table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to pull in the value from Column 4.

```
SELECT
    E.Column1
    ,E.Column2
    ,E.Column3
    ,T.Column4
FROM
(   
select Column1, Column2,Column3 from [dbo].[tabletoday]
except
select Column1, Column2,Column3 from [dbo].[Tableyesterday]
) AS E
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tabletoday] AS T
        ON
        E.Column1 = T.Column1
```